# Dapper giving "Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed." when trying to use "QueryMultiple"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dapper

I have a wrapper method for Dapper.NET's `QueryMultiple` method. It successfully gets data from a Stored Procedure, which has 3 queries, all of them are `SELECT` queries. But after getting the data, I cannot use `Read` or `ReadAsync` to assign data to class variables. I'm attaching my code below.

```
public Tuple<IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>, IEnumerable<T3>> 
        QueryMultiple<T1, T2, T3>()
    {
        try
        {
            var data = MultiQuery("[App].[USP_GetAllCategories]");
            var category = data.Read<T1>();
            var subcategory = data.Read<T2>();
            var subSubcategory = data.Read<T3>();
            return new Tuple<IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>, IEnumerable<T3>>(
                category, subcategory, subSubcategory);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public SqlMapper.GridReader MultiQuery(string storedProcedureName)
    {
        using (var connection = LocalConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                return connection.QueryMultiple(
                    sql: storedProcedureName,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseConnection(connection);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're disposing the connection before you ever call `Read`. I am not sure if dapper immediately loads the data, but the code looks wrong in any case.. there isn't really a good reason to have a method which simply wraps the `using` for you. Simply put the `using` block in `QueryMultiple`.

Comment: @Rob for reference: no, it doesn't (at least, nor in this scenario); it basically wraps an open `IDataReader`

Comment: @Rob I thought that after disposing connection, I'll still be able to use the `GridReader` to read data from. But as you can see, it doesn't seem to work. And I created the `MultiQuery` so that other developer doesn't need to know how to query, and just use `GridReader` to get data.

Comment: @haider_kazal there is no guarantee whatsoever that a reader will remain valid upon closing a connection; it is an **open** reader - we haven't actually consumed any data from the TDS stream yet

Comment: Ok... Thanks @MarcGravell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at your `MultiQuery` method. In particular, look at the `finally` block. Now consider: that block has been called before the data has been consumed. Basically, don't do that.

If it was me:

```
using (var connection = LocalConnection())
uaing (var data = conn.QueryMultiple("[App].[USP_GetAllCategories]",
    command type: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
    //... Consume
}
```

If it is helpful to write a `QueryMultipleSP` extension method that adds the command-type, then maybe do that, but...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.
However the problem is that, I need to write the `MultiQuery` function so that the developers don't need to know Database specifics, and only get a `GridReader` from which they can `Read` the data. I guess that will not be possible.

Comment: If you want to return a reader, you need to make it the client of your code's responsibility to dispose the reader and the connection. You need to document this properly in your API documentation. And, you can't use "using" on the IDisposables. You could achieve what you want implementing IDisposable in your class itself, and dispose your dependencies in your Dispose implementation. But, it's a matter of API design, I guess.

Comment: @haider_kazal you can do that, but you'd need to wrap the `GridReader` and make it the reader's responsibility to close/dispose the connection and dispose the wrapped `GridReader`.

Comment: You can wrap MultiQuery in a wrapper method that has a callback argument: `Func<SqlMapper.GridReader,T> callback`. The wrapper method will return a call to the callback inside a `using` block. It ensures the connection is always closed/disposed properly, and client code can do what it needs with the `GridReader`.

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler answer is the most correct way to do this. Took me a bit to work it out but it retains what the OP asked for. A seamless way for his dev's to make queries without dealing with sql connections.